# passing a lowercase letter to uppercase equivalent without using toUpperCase () method

Tags: java, uppercase, lowercase

I've been trying and trying and there is no way.

I want to spend a lowercase letter to uppercase equivalent.

I know and know how to use the method toUpperCase () but I want to do without it.

This is my failing code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ConvertLetters {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("enter a lower case letter");
        char letter = stdin.nextLine();
        int letter2 = 'A' + (letter - 'a');
        System.out.println("and we will refund your letter capitalized");
        System.out.print("Your letter: " + letter);
        System.out.print("upper case equates to:");
        System.out.print(letter2);
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you are only interested in ASCII conversion then?

Answer (score 2):

You want to finish with a `char`

```
char letter = stdin.nextLine().charAt(0);
char letter2 = (char) ('A' + (letter - 'a'));
```

or

```
char letter2 = (char) (letter - 32);
```

Comment: also, he should be using nextInt() and not nextLine().

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems with this code. First, you assign `nextLine()`, which is a string. You may want something like

```
char letter = stdin.nextLine().charAt(0);
```

instead. Second, you print `int`, try

```
System.out.print((char)letter2);
```

With these changes, I think your code will give you better results.

Naturally, that won't work for non-ascii characters, anyway.

Comment: Yes!, many many thanks!, it took me 3 days to get the solution